# Light text on dark background too bold on Firefox for Mac

Tags: macos, firefox

When light text is shown on a dark background on a web page, Firefox for Mac renders the font too bold. This only applies to the Mac version, the windows version renders fine.

This problem was also occurring with Safari on the Mac, however it was corrected by adding: `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` to the css code of the site.

Is there a similar code that will do the same for Firefox Mac? Already tried `opacity:0.99;` but that is no solution with this font.

Here's a test file: http://tinyurl.com/d88o2f8

Answer (score 0):

`-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale` will do the same thing in firefox on mac.